# How can I see what my simple neural network in python dream of?

Tags: python, neural-network

I have built a basic multi-layer perceptron which can learn from the MNIST dataset.
After the learning, I wanted to obtain an input from an output, meaning reversing the feedforward function in order to obtain a picture generated by the network.

My whole code is similar to https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/network.py

The feedforward function looks like:

```
def feedforward(self, a):
    """Return the output of the network if ``a`` is input."""
    for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
        a = sigmoid(np.dot(w, a)+b)
    return a
```

If I try to reverse it, using np.linalg.pinv, it doesn't work because at some point I have to inverse a vector and the solution is not unique, for example :

```
m = np.array([[3, 4]])
n = np.array([[1], [2]])
o = np.dot(m,n)
print(np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(m),o)) #not n
```

I'm stucked there. I think I need a hack to make the output of np.linalg.pinv more coherent, because as it is I don't even manage to retrieve a real input as there are logarithms in the expression of the inverse of the sigmoid function, and because of the values given by np.linalg.pinv, I end up with negative numbers resulting in NaN everywhere.

Any ideas ?

PS : the end goal is to feed random noise into the network and watch numbers appear, hence the dream expression which I picked up from http://googleresearch.blogspot.fr/2015/06/inceptionism-going-deeper-into-neural.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there is no need to reverse the network in any way, but you should create a random image and feed it to the network and see how it performs. 
Now you gradually change the input image in ways that make the output be closer to what you would like it to be. Moreover you should try to have neighboring pixels be similar to each other in intensity.

(This is basically what the provided link states in other words.)

Comment: You're right, I probably mixed things up. I still want to reverse the network to see what kind of image it can generate though, I should probably delete and rephrase, as that title brought me an insta-downvote anyway.

Also, I'm interested to know if you have any clue about how to gradually change the input image in ways that make the output be closer to what I would like it to be ?

Comment: Frankly, I am new to ML and trying to find this out myself (: Yet, about reversing the network: I am not quite sure if this is going to get one anywhere as even for a network with one output and two inputs. Assuming you know you are looking for a `z = 1` (after having inverted the sigmoid on your actually desired output). With x=y=1 as weights and a,b as the inputs you are looking for, you can have infinite solutions for the point-product `z=x*a+y*b`, can't you?

Comment: OK you convinced me, this is actually impossible or at least the wrong way of looking at things. I'll get back to it once I have more experience in the field. Thanks for answering.